# Do I use "were", "was", or "is"?

Tags: verbs, sequence-of-tenses

Sorry for the elementary question, but I am confused. Suppose I am telling someone about a conversation I had with a friend the previous day. Which would be correct?

"I asked him if he were well"

"I asked him if he is well"

"I asked him if he was well"

Am I right in saying that the third sentence would be "double past tense", as in referring to a previous conversation where I asked my friend if he was well at an even earlier point in time?

Comment: No! "Were" is arguably ungrammatical, and backshifted "was" is fine. Whether non-backshifted "is" is appropriate depends on whether the matter of his being well remains relevant, i.e. still a matter of concern at the time of the report (perhaps due to some long-term health issue). The salient interpretation though is that it was just a customary polite enquiry about his general health/wellbeing at the time of the utterance and hence backshifted "was" would seem to be the correct choice.

Answer (score 2):

No, the third form is the normal one, and does not imply a reference to an earlier time (that would be "I asked him if he had been well").

The other two are both, at best, dubious.

"I asked him if he were well" is probably not grammatical in current English, as it is a subjunctive form, which is only used for *irrealis* (counter-factual) conditions. It may have been grammatical in Early Modern English, but now I would judge it a hyper-correction (i.e. a form used by people who have had "If I was" 'corrected' to "If I were" without understanding the context in which they were corrected).

"I asked him if he is well" is unusual, as it does not follow the customary pattern of tenses in indirect speech.

Comment: Actually, *"I asked him if he had been well"* would most likely refer to a lengthy period of time when you hadn't seen your friend, and not to a specific earlier time.